# How To Edit PyDev Quick Fix Templates?

Tags: eclipse, templates, code-analysis, pydev, code-completion

I am developing a class in PyDev and as I am writing the `__init__(self)` method I realize I need to call another method.  Within `__init__` I simply type `self.otherMethod(param)` then press `Ctrl+1` and the Quick Fix window appears suggesting several option including `Create otherMethod method at A`.  When I choose to create the `otherMethod` method, the following code is automatically generated:

```
def otherMethod(self,param):
pass
```

For Python, the indentation of this is incorrect.  Is there a way to edit the template for Quick Fix?  This particular template is not available under Preferences -> PyDev -> Editor -> Templates.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.otherMethod(param)

    def otherMethod(param):
    pass
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those quick fixes are currently hard-coded, so, they cannot be editable... I went on to try to fix your use-case but I couldn't reproduce it in PyDev 2.2.3, so, please try upgrading (if you're not in the latest PyDev) or if you're already in the latest version, please create a bug-report with instructions to reproduce it (see: http://pydev.org/about.html for the proper place to create a bug-report).

Comment: Thank you for your response.  That's what I figured.  I am using 2.2.3.  Essentially, when do this within another method of a class it will create the new method within the same class.  However, the new method seems to have a mixture of spaces and tabs for indentation, which provides a mixed indentation warning in Eclipse.  I think the quick fix adds the spaces and Eclipses adds tabs to match the indentation.  Does this sound like a reasonable explanation?  I am still fairly new to Eclipse and PyDev, so this might just be an issue with my settings.

Comment: It's probably something related to tabs/spaces in that place. Please report that as a bug report (I'll take a look at it).